# Change date format for input date and pass to the function only actual date

Tags: java, html, datetime, thymeleaf

I want to put my date like a value of input date

Original format: OffsetDateTime format

For example: I have this `2021-08-21T14:06:58.147+03:00` and I want `2021-08-21`

```
 <tr class="active-row" th:each="client : ${trialUsers}">
          <td th:text="${client.firstName}"></td>
          <td th:text="${client.lastName}"></td>
          <td th:text="${client.email}"></td>
  <td> <input type="date" id="dateForUpdate" th:value="${client.myTime}"> </td>
        <td> <button class="btn" th:attr="onclick='testFunc(\'' + ${client.myTime} +'\',\''+ ${client.email} + '\');'">Extend period</button> </td>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

I have this table

```
 name | lastname | email           | time |  Change time

[Mark] [Jones]     [mark@gmail.com] [2021-08-21T14:06:58.147+03:00]

 [Button for extend period]
```

But i want this:

```
[Mark] [Jones] [mark@gmail.com] [2021-08-21] [Button for extend period]
```

I tried to use this `${#dates.format(client.myTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}`
but it doesn't work.

And I have one more question. How to pass always actual date values to the myFunc ()? After all, the user can change the date and send only old date.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+format+date+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please post relevant script and HTML instead of some ascii rendering. You likely just need to split on "T"

Comment: The `#dates.format()` function is for `java.util.Date` objects. You have a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` object. Therefore you need to use a Thymeleaf [`#temporals.format()`](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time) function, instead. This is provided in a Thymeleaf add-on JAR file.

Comment: @CringePointerException If you found a solution, please post and accept an Answer to your own Question, so this page can be marked as resolved, and so future readers may benefit.

Answer (score 0):

```
    First answer: The #dates.format() function is for java.util.Date objects. You have a java.time.OffsetDateTime object. Therefore you need to use a Thymeleaf #temporals.format() function, instead. This is provided in a Thymeleaf add-on JAR file.
```

Thanks  @andrewjames

> This is solution for second question. If you want to pass only actual
> input date use this:

```
<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>surname</td>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td>time</td>
          <th>action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="active-row" th:each="client : ${trialUsers}">
          <td th:text="${client.firstName}"></td>
          <td th:text="${client.lastName}"></td>
          <td th:text="${client.email}"></td>
          <td> <input type="date" th:id='${client.id}' th:value="${#temporals.format(client.time, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"> </td>
          <td> <button class="btn" th:attr="onclick='testFunc(\''+ ${client.id} + '\');'">change time</button> </td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <script>
          function testFunc(timeId) {
          var myTime =  document.getElementById(timeId).value;

            fetch('/register/trial/changeTime', {
              method: 'put',
              headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
              body: JSON.stringify({
                "id": timeId,
                "time": myTime,
              })
            })

                .then(function (response) {
                  return response.json();
                })
                .then(function (result) {
                 console.log("blabla")
                .
                catch (function (error) {
                  console.log("blabla")
                });
          }
        </script>
      </table>
```